# Find linear transformation using change of basis matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

> Let $\beta_1 = \{(1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1)\}$ and $\beta_2 = \{(2,1,1),(1,2,1),(-1,1,1)\}$ be two ordered bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then find a matrix representing the linear transformation $T \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ which transforms $\beta_1$ to $\beta_2$.

I think it involves using the change of basis vector from $\beta_1$ to $\beta_2$ to find the linear transformation $T$.
$$P = \beta_2^{-1}\beta_1$$
$$P = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{3}&\frac{4}{3}&\frac{1}{3}\\1&-1&0\\-\frac{2}{3}&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{2}{3}\end{bmatrix}$$
But how do I proceed from here? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: In general when you want to find the transformation matrix which changes a basis $\beta_{1} to\beta_{2}$ . Just try to express the individual $\beta_{2_{i}}$ as a linear combination of $\sum_{i}c_{i}\beta_{1_{i}}$ . Then just write each of the expressions as your columns . And you will get the required matrix

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you are interested in the linear map which maps the first vector of $\beta_1$ into the first vector of $\beta_2$, the second vector of $\beta_1$ into the second vector of $\beta_2$, and the third vector of $\beta_1$ into the third vector of $\beta_2$. If that's so, note that, since$$(1,0,0)=\frac12(1,1,0)+\frac12(1,0,1)-\frac12(0,1,1),$$then\begin{align}T(1,0,0)&=\frac12(2,1,1)+\frac12(1,2,1)-\frac12(-1,1,1)\\&=\left(2,1,\frac12\right).\end{align}A similar computation show that $T(0,1,0)=\left(0,0,\frac12\right)$ and that $T(0,0,1)=\left(-1,1,\frac12\right)$. So, take the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}2&0&-1\\1&0&1\\\frac12&\frac12&\frac12\end{bmatrix}.$$